# Subject-Verb Agreement with Singular and Plural subjects

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, verb-agreement

I'm trying to figure out how to word the following hyperbolic statement regarding dodgy building construction:

> The only sturdy thing about that building [is/are] the nails holding it together.

Which is correct in this case, *is* or *are*? Neither sounds correct.

Even if I reword the sentence, it still sounds awkward:

> The nails holding that building together [is/are] the only sturdy thing about it.

We have three subjects; two singulars and a plural. Grammatically, the main subject is the "sturdy thing", but the nails are the punchline (the context is supposed to be funny).

What's the rule here?

Comment: There is one subject in that sentence (as in pretty much any sentence), not three. In the first version, the subject is “the only sturdy thing about that building”; in the second, it “the nails holding that building together”.

Answer (score 2):

The only sturdy thing about that building [is/are] the nails holding it together.

The subject **thing** must agree in number with the verb **is**. The *nails* on the other side of the linking verb *is* is called the *predicate nominative*, which is noun or pronoun that identifies or explains the subject.

> The only sturdy thing about that building is the nails holding it
>   together.

Suggestion: *Nails are the only sturdy thing holding that building together.*

The *nails* holding that building together **are** the only sturdy thing about it. [*nails* = plural subject and *are* = plural verb]

It's called Subject/Verb Agreement.

> 5a. When a word refers to one person or thing, it is *singular* in
>   number. When a word refers to more that one, it is *plural* in number.
>
> 5b. A verb agrees with its subject in number.
>
> (1) Singular subjects take singular verbs.
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> My **friend likes** algebra. [The singular verb *likes* agrees with
>   the singular subject *friend*.]
>
> (2) Plural subjects take plural verbs.
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> My **friends like** algebra.

John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Third Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. 160.